# ActionFilterAttribute: When to use OnActionExecuting vs. OnActionExecutingAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I made a `LoggedAttribute` class that inherited from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` and put logging into `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecutingAsync` methods; I had assumed one would be used for async calls and one would be used for non-async calls, but it seems both are being used.  So which one should I put my logging in?

**UPDATE**

Code follows:

```
public sealed class LoggedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public LoggedAttribute(ILogManager logManager)
    {
        _logger = logManager.GetLogger<LoggedAttribute>();
    }

    public LoggedAttribute() : this(new LogManager()) {}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //logging logic goes here
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //logging logic goes here
        await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I then apply the [Logged] attribute to my base ApiController, and I am getting duplicate log entries for single calls.

Comment: have you applied the filter to both sync and async actions, please can you supply the code

Comment: Do you want to log if the async action is cancelled?  Call tree is OAEAsync->OAE...

Comment: I really don't care about whether it's cancelled; I just want to log requests and associated metadata.

Comment: @bri, if I understand you correctly then, I only need to put the logic into `OnActionExecuting` to get requests logged.

Comment: That's where I'm at yeah. I looked for an hour or so before pausing on the call stack -- but I didn't dig into the source or anything ;-).

Comment: It's not worthy of an "answer" man ... I didn't really do the work required to earn answer status ;-)

Comment: Two years later, someone comes and downvotes the question?  Seriously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like OnActionExecuting gets called on every single request.  I put my logic exclusively in that method, and it seems to work as desired.

Comment: If OnActionExecuting is always called, what is the using of the async method?

Comment: @Pliskin, that's a great question, and I don't have an answer.  Perhaps it's worthy of another SO question.

Comment: do i need to implement both?

Comment: in my experience... no.

Answer (score 12):

The reply doesn't answer the question I think,

Both are used if you need to run your code before executing the action.

If you want it also to be ran **SYNCHRONOUSLY** use `OnActionExecuting`, otherwise use `OnActionExecutingAsync` (e.i. Async).

Comment: do i need to implement both?

Comment: @deadManN No you don't have.

Comment: i only provide the async version... but it look like the sync version is fake and for overriding propose...